# Можно ли написать аналог java-сервиса на C#, не меняя референсы в приложении, которое использует java-сервис

Tags: java, c#, wcf, веб-служба

Возможно ли написать аналог java-сервиса на C# WCF, не изменяя референсы в приложении, которое использует java-сервис (подменить эндпоинт сервиса)?
Если возможно, то какие условия нужно соблюсти, от java-сервиса есть только WSDL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да можно, нужно просто скормить WCF сервису WSDL и все.

Сервис из метаданных можно создать с помщью утилиты: `svcutil`

Пример:

```
svcutil.exe [/t:code]  <metadataDocumentPath>* | <url>* | <epr>
```

[Тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905(v=vs.110).aspx) информация о создании WCF из метаданных.

Comment: А каким образом?

Comment: Вот так:  `svcutil your.wsdl`

Comment: @МстиславПавлов: Может быть, вы напишете пару слов о создании WCF-интерфейсов из метаданных? А то ссылки, даже на MSDN, имеют свойство умирать. Так что если рядом со ссылкой будет ещё и текст, будет реально полезно.

Comment: @VladD добавил команду. //Там как бы не о чем особо писать...

Comment: @МстиславПавлов: Класс, спасибо!

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, спасибо большое, все получилось!)

Answer (score 3):

Референс на сервис - это, по сути, лишь WSDL сервиса и сгенерированные по нему классы. Если написать веб-сервис с точно таким же интерфейсом - то никто не заметит подмены.

Чтобы написать веб-сервис по указанному WSDL, надо:

1. Сгенерировать по этому WSDL классы (например, добавив референс на существующий сервис)
2. Реализовать интерфейс сервиса
3. Настроить хостинг сервиса

Все отличие от создания веб-сервиса с нуля - лишь в том, что интерфейс у нас уже готовый и его не надо придумывать и нельзя менять.